# Custom Function not working on Stripping Text

Tags: python, pandas

I have the need to clean-up a pandas dataframe, in which there are several columns that need some data to be removed or stripped. To make a cleaner code I'm trying to create a function that can make some cleaning and return a new columns with only the stripped info I need.

As can be seen in the following code, I have tried to rewrite the code in different ways (also using lambda functions), but unfortunately I have found no fortune. I always get the error `'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

```
import pandas as pd

def cleaner(x):
    x = str(x)
    x = x.str.split('/').str[1]
    return x

data = ["First/A", "Second/B", "Third/C"]

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

dataframe.columns = ["Source"]

dataframe["Destination"] = dataframe["Source"].apply(cleaner)
```

What I'm expecting is to get a new column (destination) with only the "A", "B" "C" value.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, this is my first question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to specify `.str` for variable `x` since it is a string object.

```
def cleaner(x):
    x = str(x)
    #x = x.str.split('/').str[1]
    x = x.split('/')[1]
    return x

dataframe["Destination"] = dataframe["Source"].apply(cleaner)
```

Moreover, this can easily be reduced to,

```
dataframe["Destination"] = dataframe["Source"].str.split('/').str[1]
```

Comment: @EdoardoPiccolotto If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it as the solution :)

Comment: For second solution, I think it needs `str` after `split` with `dataframe["Destination"] = dataframe["Source"].str.split('/').str[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

def cleaner(x):
    x = x.split('/')[1]
    return x

data = ["First/A", "Second/B", "Third/C"]

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

dataframe.columns = ["Source"]

dataframe["Destination"] = dataframe.apply(lambda x: cleaner(x['Source']), axis=1)
```